# name 'sympy' is not defined

Tags: python, jupyter, sympy

Yesterday my code worked alright, but today jupyter isn´t recognizing sympy, I already checked and it is installed, what can I do?

```
from sympy import expand, symbols

x0=2
y0=4

x1=5
y1=1

x =symbols("x")

L0=sympy.expand((x-x1)/(x0-x1))*y0
L1=sympy.expand((x-x0)/(x1-x0))*y1

print ("L0= ",L0)
print ("L1= ",L1)
               
print ("px= ",L0+L1)
```

Error Stack Trace:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-9cbabedcf78d> in <module>
      9 x =symbols("x")
     10 
---> 11 L0=sympy.expand((x-x1)/(x0-x1))*y0
     12 L1=sympy.expand((x-x0)/(x1-x0))*y1
     13 

NameError: name 'sympy' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have expand already imported as in here:

```
from sympy import expand, symbols
```

Run these two lines like this without using `sympy.` like this:

```
L0=expand((x-x1)/(x0-x1))*y0
L1=expand((x-x0)/(x1-x0))*y1
```

Also just in case run this in your jupyter notebook and make sure `sympy` is installed:

```
pip list
```

Comment: Kindly accept this answer since it worked for you, glad to help! :)